# How powerful was Brahmastra?

Tags: weapon, brahmastra

There's a weapon discussed in Mahabharata called *Brahmastra*. Maybe Bhishma and Drona had this weapon.

How powerful was it? If any person used it, would it destroy whole world? Was there any technique/way to respond to it and make it fail once it is released by someone? Or once released, it will destroy the world?

EDIT: Now since it seems a duplicate, let me add more details to clarify why I need answer for it.

In a few answers earlier on different questions, I read that "Arjuna or someone fired Brahmastra on Karna. The story after being fired is not described. Nobody knows what happened." Then the author concluded that since Karna was still alive, **it must have been destroyed with ordinary arrows.**

Unfortunately, I can't find those questions and answers, but I'm sure I read it.

EDIT 2: If you still not ready to remove it as duplicate, let me add further details. In Star Plus Mahabharata, it is shown that Brahmastra fired by Ashwathama attacks only the womb of Uttara. No point of destroying whole world. **Secondly**, it is also shown that Brahmastra fired by Arjuna to counter attack Ashwathama's Brahmastra, withdrawn back by Arjuna after Krishna told him to do so.

Comment: You can see a similar question here - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/18961/do-scriptures-describe-the-effects-of-brahmastra

Comment: And a quite useful answer here - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2945/5620

Comment: "Was there any technique/way to respond to it and make it fail once it is released by someone? " -- yes, Brahmadanda astra can be used to counter it https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/26252/12304 ...and i don't think Bhishma had it, did u read it somewhere?

Comment: @YDS serials :P

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do scriptures describe the effects of Brahmastra?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/18961/do-scriptures-describe-the-effects-of-brahmastra) and [What is the story behind the Brahmasthra? Was it actually ever fired?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2942/5212)

Comment: @SwiftPushkar my question is partially answered there. Please check my edit.

Comment: Add this to title to make your question unique: Once launched, can it be withdrawn?

Comment: @sv. *Once launched, can it be withdrawn?* this is opinion based :P

Comment: @Vikas you query is abt Brahmastra or Brahmashirshastra? your edit2 is actually for Brahmashirshastra...

Comment: @YDS in serial both said Brahmastra.

Comment: BTW I don't see any Karna supporter here now.

Comment: @Vikas regarding ur q abt Karna, can u confirm if this happened before he donated his kavacha kundla or after donating them??..if before then it might hv been neutralized by kavacha kundala instead of normal arrows...intention of the guy who used Bhramastra is also important like he wanted to tie him or kill him etc...

Comment: "let me add more details to clarify why I need answer for it."Question closure depends on the type of question asked. If the question is same and you are not satisfied with answer present, it is still a duplicate. Original Mahabharata need not to follow Star plus Mahabharat serial. Your questions are entirely depending on serial and wrong plot of those serials. This makes your question prejudice wrong. If that is the case, correcting what exactly happened in the Mahabharat is enough to answer your question and not answering how powerful is a Brahmastra. This is not useful to you or the site.

Comment: Your edits also add new questions which are not present already. These questions are called as Chameleon questions. Edits should not change the question entirely. But your edits are making like that. As mentioned above, just correcting wrong assumptions is enough for answering.Due to this, answers received will not be satisfying. So, don't base questions entirely on serials. Make some research if they are true or not. Also don't make drastic changes to questions. Your question is still a duplicate. If your question has many questions, it is a too broad question.

Answer (score 0):

The divine weapon with no match, which was used by Aswatthama is not bramAstra, but  [brahmashira](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m10/m10012.htm),  is capable of consuming the whole world.

According to the Mahabharata, it acts at the wish of the user.

Ashvatthama, who was no match to Arjuna, uttered in wrath, while discharging **brahmashira**,  these terrible words: ‘**[For the destruction of the Pandavas](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m10/m10013.htm)**.

At the behest of Krishna, Arjuna also discharged **brahmashira** to contain the one discharged by Ashvatthama, thinking of the welfare of [**all the worlds**](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m10/m10014.htm) and uttering the words, **‘Let Ashvatthama's weapon be neutralised by this weapon!'**.

Fearing collision of 2 **brahmashira** weapons, Sage Narada and Sage Vyasa stop them, by standing between them. Later at the advise of Sage Vyasa, Arjuna withdraws the **brahmashira** discharged by him.

As Ashvatthama is incapable of withdrawing his weapon, [changes the direction](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m10/m10015.htm) towards wombs of the Pandava women.  The foetus in the Uttara's womb dies due to its attack.

Comment: Was a capable of consuming whole world. So why it killed only fetus?

Comment: Please go through the answer again@Vikas

Comment: Cool thanks. But my question is partially answered.

Comment: Please check again. It answered all the questions @Vikas

Comment: all questions are already answered in this world. I'm on of those who don't understand the answer or feels it is partially answered. Going again and again won't answer my doubts mentioned in question.

Comment: @Vikas:what is your doubt that remained unanswered? please explain

Comment: Please go through question details again.